# C# - On occurrence of an exception, want to retain original state of parameter object with any recent changes

Tags: c#, exception

Calling method passes an object to calle method, where calle method tries to modify the values of the received object properties while doing modification if some exception occurs, exception will be thrown to the calling method but the object received is semi/partially modified(because objects are referenced type)

The semi/partially filled is something I would like to avoid, on occurrence of exception would like to set the object passed between method  as null or it should with original state without have any of the recent state changes. How to achieve it in c#?

Sample code:

```
  class MyClass
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }

        public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }

        [MyCustomAttribute]
        public int MyProperty3 { get; set; }

    }


    MyClass DoSomething1(MyClass myClass)
    {
        try
        {
            var updatedClass = new MyClass();

            updatedClass.MyProperty = 1;

            updatedClass.MyProperty2 = 2;

            MyClass fullyUpdatedClass = DoSomething2(updatedClass);

            return fullyUpdatedClass;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //2. receives partially filled myClass, even though 
            //assigned 'null' on the catch block of calle i.e., 
            //DoSomething2(), why? this behavior or I did something wrong?
            return myClass;
        }

    }

    //as per my business req., this function will updated only those properties 
    //decorated with [MyCustomAttribute]
    MyClass DoSomething2(MyClass myClass)
    {
        try
        {
            var updatedClass = new MyClass();

            //as per my business req., since MyProperty3 decorated with [MyCustomAttribute]
            //ONLY it is getting updated here.
            updatedClass.MyProperty3 = 1;

            //@Patrick Mcvay, if I do like you have suggested below 
            //changes happened on "myClass" instance via DoSomething1() will be gone 
            myClass = updatedClass;

            return myClass;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //1. though I am assigning null value here for targetted object,
            //calling code (i.e., catch block of DoSomething1()) not receiving null object, instead partially filled obj. WHY?
            myClass = null;
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you adverse to making a custom class that stores original and modified data?

Comment: Show code please. This can be accomplished fairly easy

Comment: Thought about the above mentioned custom class approach, but it doesnt seems like right fit for requirement. Reason "calle" method will only changes those object properties which are having special decorator attribute on top of it, so in order to find which are the properties are recently modified, I have to use reflection which may leads to perf. overhead. So looking for any other better alternative. Please advice if you aware of any other better option specifically any platform provided service to handle this situation.

Comment: @191180rk sorry about the late reply. You need to return null in your catch block on DoSomething2() and don't throw the exception. So basically, replace the myClass = null; throw ex; with return null;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a console application to demonstrate and I have put fairly detailed comments in the code. Just copy this into a new console application and run it.

```
public class Program
{
    // Example of the Program Class having an instance that is being updated
    // in this case your methods would just be voids and you wouldn't have to
    // pass in an instance of MyClass
    //static MyClass myClass;

    // This is an example of a value that the program knows about (that is outside of the methods, but being updated by the methods)
    static string message;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myClass = new MyClass();

        var updatedClass = DoSomething1(myClass);

        // Simply checking to see if updatedClass is null and changing the message accordingly
        message += updatedClass != null ? string.Format("\nProp 1: {0} \nProp 2: {1} \nProp 3: {2}", updatedClass.MyProperty, updatedClass.MyProperty2, updatedClass.MyProperty3) : "\nException occured returned null";

        Console.WriteLine(message);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    // Note: since you are passing in an instance of MyClass, the rest of the program
    // does not know what is happening to this instance inside the method
    // i.e. assigning null to myClass will not return null unless you specifically
    // tell it to "return myClass;" afterwards or just "return null;"
    static MyClass DoSomething1(MyClass myClass)
    {
        try
        {
            // Unless you are working with an external instance of this class you won't need to make a new MyClass instance
            // i.e. if your Program class (in a console app) has an instance that you are updating.
            // see example above
            //var updatedClass = myClass;

            myClass.MyProperty = 1;

            // Using to throw exception (Change to anything but 0 to not throw exception)
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the value for i in DoSomething1(), putting 0 will throw an exception");
            int i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            myClass.MyProperty2 = 2/i;

            myClass = DoSomething2(myClass);

            // insert breakpoint here to see what is being returned
            return myClass;

        }
        // Note: this will not catch the exception in DoSomething2() since it is already being handled in that method
        // If you want it to catch the exception from DoSomething2() you will need to put the throw; back in
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Just updating the message value to tell you which method the exception was thrown in
            message += string.Format("\nException thrown in DoSomething1()\n{0}", ex.Message);
            // Just return null here
            return null;
        }

    }

    // Note: since you are passing in an instance of MyClass, the rest of the program
    // does not know what is happening to this instance inside the method
    // i.e. assigning null to myClass will not return null unless you specifically
    // tell it to "return myClass;" afterwards or just "return null;"
    //as per my business req., this function will updated only those properties 
    //decorated with [MyCustomAttribute]
    static MyClass DoSomething2(MyClass myClass)
    {
        try
        {
            // Unless you are working with an external instance of this class you won't need to make a new MyClass instance
            // i.e. if your Program class (in a console app) has an instance that you are updating.
            // see example above
            //var updatedClass = myClass;

            // Using to throw exception (Change to anything but 0 to not throw exception)
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the value for i in DoSomething2(), putting 0 will throw an exception");
            int i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //as per my business req., since MyProperty3 decorated with [MyCustomAttribute]
            //ONLY it is getting updated here.
            myClass.MyProperty3 = 1/i;

            // return the updated MyClass object
            // insert breakpoint here to see what is being returned
            return myClass;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Just updating the message value to tell you which method the exception was thrown in
            message += string.Format("Exception thrown in DoSomething2()\n{0}", ex.Message);
            // returning null will make the entire object equal to null per the current code
            // note that only the catch in DoSomething2() is being used this way
            return null;

            // Use this if you want DoSomething1() to catch the exception
            // At this point there is really no reason for the Try Catch block
            // Unless you want to actually do something instead of just throwing the exception
            // Also, if you throw the exception here, assigning null to myClass
            // is doing nothing, because you are not returning the myClass instance.
            // like i said above the rest of the program has no idea what you
            // are doing to the myClass instance inside the method
            // uncomment the line below to show where both catch blocks are being used
            //throw;
        }

    }
}


class MyClass
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }

    //[MyCustomAttribute]
    public int MyProperty3 { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: One correction in the above example required to align with my requirement, here I have to pass MyClass OBJECT to DoSomething(). Where as in your example, you are instantiating MyClass type inside DoSomething() & that is the diff. between your example & my actual requirement.

Comment: I am instantiating only for the purpose of updating the properties (assuming this is where the exception would occur). Then I assign the myClass to the value of updatedClass and return myClass (which is the original instance passed in the method).

Comment: @ Patrick Mcvay, In my question, modified your example with my requirement. Please suggest.

Comment: @191180rk I have updated my answer to better explain everything for you.